# ruby on rails session controller InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error. I think there is a problem with sessions. Anyone have an idea?

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in SessionsController#create 
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

```
RAILS_ROOT: /home/rails/app/
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace 
/home/rails/app/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/request_forgery_protection.rb:79:in `verify_authenticity_token'
/home/rails/app/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should clear your cookies. Perhaps, you have deployed a different site under the same hostname. If this alone does not help, check if you have set up constant DOMAIN or SESSION_DOMAIN in your config (I had them in config/environments/production.rb), adjust them, and restart your server.